# Floating an image/icon to the left of a text

Tags: html, css

[image]I'm having trouble floating an image or an icon to the left of the word Baltimore.  I've tried different icon and img floats but I'm stumped.  Below is my code and a picture of what it currently looks like.  Any help would be great. :)

```
<a onclick="myTeamFunc()" href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-block w3-white w3-left-align" id="myTeamBtn">Shop By Team<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="team" class="w3-bar-block w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
      <ul class="teamslist">
        <li>
          <p>Arizona</p>
        <li>
          <p style="line-height: 10px">
            <img src="images/nfl_icons/balt_icon.svg" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"/>Baltimore
          </p>
          <!-- <a href="#"id="baltimore" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><span class="balticon">Baltimore Ravens</span></a> -->
        </li>
          <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Team USA</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: looks like it doesnt fit, have you tried to give it more space?

Comment: As sarbot said, it seems the image and the text together don't fit on a same line. Try making the image smaller.

Comment: I've adjusted the size of the img and it still stays to the top of the text instead of the left as i wish it could. :(
I've added the following screenshot with the image smaller as well as the additional css 
`p > img {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
`

Comment: Can you please add relevant CSS code as well?

Comment: Hi @RickardElimää, I'm only using this so far for the icon:
`p > img {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}`

Comment: SVG can behave strangely in an IMG tag. I prefer using it as a background but I can't show you an example because you haven't provided enough CSS so it might look like your page. You need to provide enough code to make your error reproducable.